# BigQuery - "for loop like" operations to help mass insert rows to a table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, subquery, sql-insert

I have a simple menu table which describes the price of different sizes of different dishes. Three columns, dish name, dish size and price. For each dish I have three sizes, S, M and L.

The problem is that currently in the table not all dishes have prices for all three size, and we are planing adding more dishes to the menu table. So in the end I want the menu to have prices for all existing and new dishes for all three sizes. I am thinking of first adding in all the new dishes, and then loop through all the dishes in the table, for those sizes that does not have a price, input the default price into it. But I didn't find a way to do for loop and if checks using big query. Not sure if this is supported by sql, and do we have any solution on how to achieve it?

Default price for all dishes:
S - $6, M - $8, L - $9

current table:

```
Dish.         size.         price.
fried rice    S             $6
fried rice    L             $8.5
pancake       S             $5
pancake       M             $7    
pancake       L             $9
corn soup     S             $6
corn soup     M             $8
corn soup     L             $9
salad         M             $6.5
salad         S             $4
snack mix     M             $6
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't loop! SQL is a set-based language, that provides all the tools you  need to solve this with a single statement.

You can `cross join` the list of distinct dishes with a fixed list of sizes (along with their default price), filter out tuples that exist already with `not exists`, and `insert` the results in the table:

```
insert into mytable (dish, size, price)
select d.dish, s.size, s.price
from (select distinct dish from mytable) d
cross join (
    select 'S' size, 6 price
    union all select 'M', 8
    union all select 'L', 9
) s
where not exists (select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.dish = d.dish and t1.size = s.size)
```

Comment: Cool, this works as magic!!! thanks a lot. Just wondering, if I have got all my new dishes in another table and have not added the name of those new dishes to mytable, can we achieve the same purpose by modifying the above query?